# Where does symbol once come from?

Tags: java, junit, jmock

I'm trying to work through an article (http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) on mocking with pseudocode in it that I'm implementing, but I'm having trouble finding *once* (and *eq*, *returnValue*, etc.).

I first wanted to use jMock 2.5.1, but it's too recent compared to the article. Then I tried jMock 1.2.0. I can't find where to get *once*.

I've grep'd through jMock, EasyMock and Hamcrest sources so far without having found *once* as an indentifier of any sort.

Googling for *returnValue* let alone *once* hasn't been very helpful either: code that uses these symbols is uniformly posted without import statements.

Thanks for any direction you can give me.

Comment: can you post a link to the article?

Comment: I added the URL to my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jMock will contain the functionality to perform *once* but it may not actually contain the static method *once*. I believe the jMock equivalence will be [one](http://www.jmock.org/cardinality.html).

If you are looking at pseudocode for a static method *once*, it is more than likely coming from [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/). EasyMock definitely has the static method *once* to describe the situation where an expected mock object method call should happen once and only once.

Comment: The pseudocode claimed to be using jMock. I'm agnostic about this, but I did want to remain within the arena suggested by the author. I guess I'll investigate EasyMock to see if I'm able to implement the pseudocode without deviating too much from the author's intent. (The article IS about mocking and NOT about jMock in particular.) Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... I downloaded EasyMock, wired it in and once is still missing. I extracted the sources and samples, grep'd them and failed to find once as an indentifier anywhere.

Comment: The once I was referring to is here: http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/IExpectationSetters.html but this is not what you are looking for. The once you are looking for is here: http://www.jmock.org/javadoc/1.1.0/org/jmock/MockObjectTestCase.html and seems to have been removed from the early versions of the API

Comment: How disappointing: I see code all over using once, but with no indication as to import statements or JAR versions. It's tough to learn something when you have to sort through so much obsolete junk. "This isn't the article you want to read." Guess I'll move on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

jMock 2 is a complete rewrite and the syntax has changed. The `oneOf()` method is now within the `Expectations` class. There are examples shipped with the code.